# Dynamic Positioning of Label in Responsive react-echarts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, echarts, apache-echarts

I have a react web application using echarts-for-react. I've set values that accurately reflect my UI requirements but the problem started when I made it responsive. The position, offset and distance for label are fixed numeric values and not percentage. So when I resize the screen and therefore chart also. The label position gets changed. Is there any way to fix it so that on changing the size, the position of label is changed properly without getting misplaced ???

`

```
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react"

var builderJson = {
  "all": 100,
  "total": 1000,
  "charts": {
    "A": 10,
    "B": 20,
    "C": 30
  },
};
const options = {
     
    grid: {
        containLabel: true,
        height: '60%'
    },
    xAxis: {
      show : false,
      type: 'value'
    },
    yAxis: {
       data: Object.keys(builderJson.charts),
       type: 'category',
       axisLabel: {
            show: false,
        },
        splitLine: {
            show: false
        },
        axisLine: {
            show: false
        },
        axisTick: {
            show: false,
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            color: 'blue',
            type: 'bar',
            barCategoryGap: '10%',
            barWidth: '40%',
            stack: 'total',
            groupPadding: 3,
            label: {
              color: 'black',
              position: [0, -16],
              formatter: function(param) { return param.name },
              show: true
            },
            itemStyle: {
                borderRadius: [0, 2, 2, 0],
            },
            data: Object.keys(builderJson.charts).map(function (key) {
                return builderJson.charts[key];
            })
        },
        {
            type: 'bar',
            barWidth: '40%',
            stack: 'total',
            barCategoryGap: '10%',
            color: 'whitesmoke',
            groupPadding: 3,
            label: {
                show: true,
                distance: 15,
                position: 'insideBottomRight',
                offset: [-50, 0],
                color: 'grey',
                formatter: function(params) { return builderJson.all - params.value + '%' }
            },
            data: Object.keys(builderJson.charts).map(function (key) {
                return builderJson.all - builderJson.charts[key];
            })
        },
        {
            type: 'bar',
            stack: 'total',
            barWidth: '40%',
            barCategoryGap: '10%',
            color: 'whitesmoke',
            groupPadding: 3,
            label: {
                show: true,
                position: 'insideBottomRight',
                offset: [20,-10],
                formatter: function(params) { return builderJson.total }
            },
            data: Object.keys(builderJson.charts).map(function (key) {
                return 0;
            })
        }
    ]
  
}

function App() {
  return (
    <ReactEcharts
      option={options}
      style={{ 
        width: "100%", height: "100vw" 
      }}
    ></ReactEcharts>
  )
}

export default App
```

`

Gives following output in certain height and width scaling :-[image]

But when the height changes, the label get placed in wrong part :-[image]

Any help on how to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust position of the labels using labelLayout property like this

```
...
...
 series: [
  {
    name: '',
    label: '',
    labelLayout: (params)=>{
      return {
        y: params.rect.y - 100,
        x: params.rect.x - 85,
        draggable: true
      }
    },
    type: '',
    yAxisIndex: 0,
    data: '',
    color: '',
  },
...
...
```

*params.rect.y* and *params.rect.y* represents the coordinate of each label. this might not answer your question directly. but hope this will give you some insight.